# How do I make a secondary <View> enter a main view with the PanResponder?

Tags: ios, react-native, view

When the View mounts, I would like the secondary view to be *off the screen* to the right of the main view.

When the user pan swipes *left*, the secondary view should follow the pan and eventually cover the main view. (like Instagram camera)

I have a basic structure set up, but I'm not sure how to finalize the `<Animated.View>` part.  For example, do I put the pan handler on the main view or on the secondary view?  I don't want the secondary view to cover any interactions on the main view.

```
import React from 'react';
import { PanResponder, Animated, Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
const winWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width
const winHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height

class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    translateX = new Animated.Value(0);
    panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (e, gs) => {
            return gs.dx < 0 //allow left only
        },
        onPanResponderMove: (e, gs) => { 
            if(gs.dx < 0) { 
                Animated.event([null, {dx: this.translateX}])(e, gs) 
            }
        },
        onPanResponderRelease: (e, {vx, dx}) => {
            //Secondary View should now cover the main View
        },
        onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (e, gs) => {
            return false 
        },
        onPanResponderTerminate: (e, {vx, dx} ) => {
        },
    })
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={{styles.main}}>
                <View style={{styles.secondary}}></View>
                <View><Text>Other components will be displayed</Text></View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    main:{
        flex:1,
        flexDirection:'column',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
    },
    secondary:{
        width: winWidth,
        height: winHeight,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        position: 'absolute',
        top:0,
        left:winWidth, //start off screen
    },
})
```

Comment: Never had to deal with panhandler myself, I use this awesome library https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/component-drawer-layout.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are after but the way I did it was nesting two View inside the Animated.View Component which cover the full screen.

```
<Animated.View style={[this.position.getLayout(), {display: 'flex', flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}]} {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}>
    <View style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
        <Text>
            This is the Main view
        </Text>
    </View>

    <View style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
        <Text>
            This is the invisible View
        </Text>     
    </View>
</Animated.View>
```

- The styling in the Views is to make each cover the full width
- inside the Animated.View I used the array notation to apply two styles
- **this.position.getLayout()** is the one that gives the coordinates/position of where the Animated.View component should be
- The other styling object is so we can render the child views next to each other using flexbox particularly setting
- Also attach the panHandlers to the Animated.View

  ```
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    position = new Animated.ValueXY()

    const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: ()=> true,
        onPanResponderMove: (evt, gesture)=>{
            //Need to set theshhold and state.isOpen to determine direction here
            position.setValue({x: gesture.dx, y: 0})
        },
        onPanResponderGrant: ()=>{
            this.position.setOffset({x: this.position.x._value, y: 0})
            this.position.setValue({x: 0, y: 0})
        },
        onPanResponderRelease: ()=>{
            this.openOrClose()        
        }
    })

    this.state = {isOpen: false} 
    this.panResponder = panResponder
    this.position = position
  }
  ```
- I used state to monitor where the View Should move to **this.state = {isOpen: false}** depending on which view was visible.
- The functions to move are mainly **position.setValue({x: gesture.dx, y: 0})** which tracks the movement while the touch/pan is still active and **this.openOrClose()** which is called when the touch/pan is released.
- The openOrClose function determines how to handle the movement and the main logic should be here. I just did a simple case and did not include any threshHold in this example.
- To understand panHandlers I suggest you read [this article](https://mindthecode.com/getting-started-with-the-panresponder-in-react-native/) as it explains the reasons for **onPanResponderGrant** best.

Below is the code for the working Component

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View, Text, Animated, PanResponder, Dimensions} from 'react-native'

const ScreenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width

//Logic to flattenOffset required
export class Swipable extends Component{
 constructor(props){
  super(props)
  position = new Animated.ValueXY()

  const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
   onStartShouldSetPanResponder: ()=> true,
   onPanResponderMove: (evt, gesture)=>{
    //Need to set theshhold and state.isOpen to determine direction here
    position.setValue({x: gesture.dx, y: 0})
   },
   onPanResponderGrant: ()=>{
    this.position.setOffset({x: this.position.x._value, y: 0})
    this.position.setValue({x: 0, y: 0})
   },
   onPanResponderRelease: ()=>{
    this.openOrClose()  
   }
  })

  this.state = {isOpen: false} 
  this.panResponder = panResponder
  this.position = position
 }

 openOrClose = ()=>{
  this.position.flattenOffset()
  //determine where to move depending onState
  direction = this.state.isOpen ? 0 : -ScreenWidth

  Animated.spring(this.position, {
   toValue: {x: direction, y: 0}
  }).start(()=>{
   //Callback when animation is complete to show if open or closed
   this.setState((prevState)=>{
     return {isOpen: !prevState.isOpen}
   })
  })
 }

 render(){
  return(
   <Animated.View style={[this.position.getLayout(), {display: 'flex', flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}]} {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}>
    <View style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
     <Text>
      This is the Main view
     </Text>
    </View>
    
    <View style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
     <Text>
      This is the invisible View
     </Text>  
    </View>
   </Animated.View>
  )
 }
}
```

I ran the above code on an Android emulator, I am sure it will work on ios. If there is anything I need to clarify or improve please do tell me